# What does 'high' refer to in Taylor Swift's 'Blank Space'?

Tags: phrases, lyrics

From Taylor Swift's song [Blank Space](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/taylorswift/blankspace.html):

> So it's gonna be forever
>
> Or it's gonna go down in flames
>
> You can tell me when it's over
>
> **If the high was worth the pain**
>
> Got a long list of ex-lovers
>
> They'll tell you I'm insane
>
> Cause you know I love the players
>
> And you love the game

What does the word **high** refer to?

Comment: High in this contex is a state of euphoria, meaning intense happiness or intense excitement.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/high?s=t definition # 39 _Slang_ **a.** a euphoric state induced by alcohol, drugs, etc.  
**b.** a period of sustained excitement, exhilaration, or the like:   
After winning the lottery he was on a high for weeks.

Answer (score 3):

From the Oxford English dictionary, there are two relevant definitions:

> Feeling euphoric, especially from the effects of drugs or alcohol
>
> A state of high spirits or euphoria

In the song, the relationship of Taylor Swift's character and the boy she is singing about/to can be taken almost like a drug trip (colloquially known as a 'high') - there will be an amazing point ("I could show you incredible things", "I could make the bad guys good for a weekend") but if it doesn't work out, then there will be a nasty descent ("Or it's gonna go down in flames").

Getting the good parts means also enduring the bad, and Taylor's character is obviously self-aware enough to note that fact, and so asks rhetorically whether the joy of the former outweighed the pain of the latter.

The video which [accompanies the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-ORhEE9VVg) provides illustrative examples of the two states.